# Extracting information from sentence : NER or other ways?

Tags: nlp, classification, named-entity-recognition

What I'm trying to do now is extracting 'customers'names' from a firm's disclosure text.

What I have done up to now stated as below:

1. Classify every sentences in disclosure data whether it contains information about its customers or not by machine learning(1 if it contains customer data, 0 if not)

So, I got sentences that marked as 1 and below are the examples of those sentences.

> *Sentence no.1>
> For the fiscal year ended on December 31, 2008, FAW Jiefang Automotive
> Co., Ltd. Dongfeng Axle Co., Ltd. ShiYan Automobile Works and FAW
> Qingdao Automobile Works accounted for approximately 6.5%, 6.0% and
> 5.3% of total sales revenue, respectively.
>
> *Sentence No 2.>
> ;;;;;PRINCIPAL CUSTOMERS In fiscal 2004, the Company
> derived approximately 38% ($14,706,748) of its consolidated revenues
> from continuing operations from direct transactions with The Home
> Depot, Inc.
>
> *sentence No 3.>
> ;;;;;Delphi Corporation is the Rubber Groups largest customer.

I want to extract "**FAW Jiefang Automotive, Co., Ltd. Dongfeng Axle Co., Ltd. ShiYan Automobile Works and FAW Qingdao Automobile Works**" from sentence 1, 'T**he Home Depot**' from sentence 2, and **'Delphi'** from sentence 3. (But not the words like Rubber Groups from sentence 3 since it's not a customer's name)

Basically, I thought that this is similar to the ***NER problem (Named Entity Recognition)***. So I tagged every words in those sentences.

For example,

> sentence 1> [('For', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('fiscal', 'JJ',
> 'O'), ('year', 'NN', 'O'), ('ended', 'VBN', 'O'), ('on', 'IN', 'O'),
> ('December', 'NNP', 'O'), ('31', 'CD', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('2008',
> 'CD', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), **('FAW', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'),
> ('Jiefang', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Automotive', 'NNP',
> 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Co.', 'NNP', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Ltd.',
> 'NNP', 'O'), ('Dongfeng', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Axle', 'NNP',
> 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Co.', 'NNP', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Ltd.',
> 'NNP', 'O'), ('ShiYan', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Automobile',
> 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Works', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('and',
> 'CC', 'O'), ('FAW', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Qingdao', 'NNP',
> 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Automobile', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Works',
> 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION')**, ('accounted', 'VBD', 'O'), ('for', 'IN',
> 'O'), ('approximately', 'RB', 'O'), ('6.5', 'CD', 'O'), ('%', 'NN',
> 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('6.0', 'CD', 'O'), ('%', 'NN', 'O'), ('and',
> 'CC', 'O'), ('5.3', 'CD', 'O'), ('%', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'),
> ('total', 'JJ', 'O'), ('sales', 'NNS', 'O'), ('revenue', 'NN', 'O'),
> (',', ',', 'O'), ('respectively', 'RB', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')]
>
> Sentence no2> [(';', ':', 'O'), (';', ':', 'O'), (';', ':', 'O'),
> (';', ':', 'O'), (';', ':', 'O'), ('PRINCIPAL', 'NNP', 'O'),
> ('CUSTOMERS', 'NNPS', 'O'), ('In', 'IN', 'O'), ('fiscal', 'JJ', 'O'),
> ('2004', 'CD', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Company',
> 'NNP', 'O'), ('derived', 'VBD', 'O'), ('approximately', 'RB', 'O'),
> ('38', 'CD', 'O'), ('%', 'NN', 'O'), ('(', '(', 'O'), ('$', '$', 'O'),
> ('14,706,748', 'CD', 'O'), (')', ')', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('its',
> 'PRP$', 'O'), ('consolidated', 'JJ', 'O'), ('revenues', 'NNS', 'O'),
> ('from', 'IN', 'O'), ('continuing', 'VBG', 'O'), ('operations', 'NNS',
> 'O'), ('from', 'IN', 'O'), ('direct', 'JJ', 'O'), ('transactions',
> 'NNS', 'O'), ('with', 'IN', 'O'), ('The', 'DT', 'O'), **('Home', 'NNP',
> 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Depot', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION')**, (',', ',',
> 'O'), ('Inc', 'NNP', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')]
>
> Sentence no3
> [(';', ':', 'O'), (';', ':', 'O'), (';', ':', 'O'), (';', ':', 'O'),
> (';', ':', 'O'), **('Delphi', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION')**, ('Corporation',
> 'NNP', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Rubber', 'NNP',
> 'O'), ('Groups', 'NNP', 'O'), ('largest', 'JJS', 'O'), ('customer',
> 'NN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')]

And I trained based on ;
those tagged data (about 3700 setences) + basic features used on NER classification (**previous and next 5 words, the shape of words (upper, title, contains digit etc,), previous words IOB tag**)

I tried almost every machine learning techniques including MLP, however, the classification is far from accurate.

I think this is because, the word classified as customer according to my tag rule, not only affected by some previous and next n words but by the type and the structure of whole sentence. For example, from sentence 1, for FAW Jiefang Automotive Co to be tagged as 'ORGANIZATION' the machine (computer) should notice that it belongs to the 'Subject chunk' which is followed by 'accounted for ~ of revenue' that is a very important feature for the classification decision.

**To sum up, I am looking for a NER machine learning techniques that can deal with the problem (NER classification that can also deal with the feature of whole sentence) stated above.**

Or would it be wiser to use other ways instead of NER?